# Grails: How to write traits for domain classes?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, traits

I would to write a trait that several domain classes would share. For example I have two domain classes as such

```
class Comment{

   String description

   static hasMany = [replies: CommentReply]

   String getFormattedDescription(){
        // ...
         return formattedDescription
   }
}

class CommentReply{
   String description

   Comment comment

   String getFormattedDescription(){
        // ...
         return formattedDescription
   }
}
```

In this case, both Comment and CommentReply have same function getFormattedDescription() which can be moved to a trait and be implemented by the two domains classes. How can I achieve this?

How do I write traits that all domain classes would implement? For example GormEntity is implemented by all domains by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to write the trait and mark it with `@Enhances('Domain')`.

```
import grails.artefact.Enhances

@Enhances('Domain')
trait YourTraitName {
    // ...
}
```

That will add `YourTraitName` to all domain classes.

In order for that to work you will need to configure the trait to be compiled in its own source set before your application code.  A common way to manage that is to have the trait in a plugin (which could be part of a multi project build).

Comment: Thank you @Jeff Scott Brown. I will give this a try.